# How do I mark the concourse ci build failed if the tests failed?

Tags: jmeter, concourse

I am running some automated tests using concourse ci pipeline. My requirement is to mark the build as failed if any of the tests failed and email the results. Is there a way to do this in concourse? The email feature is working fine, but the build passes even with the test failures.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the exit code is correct you will need to use the on failure step on concourse and add that to your job, it will look something like this

```
jobs:
- name: myBuild 
  plan:      
  - get: your-repo
    passed: []
    trigger: false
  - task: run-tests
    file: runMyTestsTask.yml   
  on_failure:
  - put: send-an-email
    params:
      subject_text: "Your email subect i.e Failed Build"
      body_text: "Your message when the build has failed"
  on_success:
    put: push-my-build

## Define your additional resources here

resources:
- name: send-an-email
  type: email
  source:
    smtp:
      host: smtp.example.com
      port: "587" # this must be a string
      username: a-user
      password: my-password
    from: build-system@example.com
    to: [ "dev-team@example.com", "product@example.net" ] #optional if `params.additional_recipient` is specified

resource_types:
  - name: email
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: pcfseceng/email-resource
```

Additionally if you need to output some relevant information about the build, you can do so by including some environment vars that will wrap the concourse metadata and you can include that into the body of the email message, for more details on how to do this, please refer to documentation of the email resource here: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/email-resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you're [running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) your command needs to return [non-zero exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)

Even if there are failures in your test the JMeter process has `0` exit code therefore any CI system will treat the execution as successful:

[image]

If you're looking for a JMeter-only solution you can add a [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/) to your Test Plan and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    props.put('failure', 'true')
}
```

Then add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and put [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) there with the following code:

```
if (props.get('failure').equals('true')) {
    System.exit(1)
}
```

if any Sampler in the JSR223 Assertion [Scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) fails - the whole JMeter process will finish with exit code `1` which is treated as error by any upstream processing system.

[image]

---

Another option is considering using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as the wrapper for your [JMeter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) test, Taurus provides flexible [pass/fail criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) which allows you possibility to define thresholds for considering test successful or not. If the thresholds are exceeded - Taurus will return non-zero exit code which should be "understood" by the concourse (or whatever else software)